Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8000 in Nuxt 3
I’m working on a Nuxt 3 project and encountering the following error:
[nitro] [unhandledRejection] connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8000

This error occurs when I try to make API requests to my backend during development. I suspect it’s related to the frontend (Nuxt 3) server  not running or being misconfigured, but I’m not sure how to resolve it.
It happen when I try to get tokens from the backend when the app start. So I try to call the backend in middleware/auth.global.ts and in plugin/initail.ts like this to make sure that user token is set to the state (I am using Pinia for state management)
import useAuthStore from "~/store/useAuthStore";
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async () => {
    const authStore = useAuthStore();

    if (!authStore.isAuthenticated) {
        // Call the backend here
        await authStore.checkAuthState();
    }
});

import useAuthStore from "~/store/useAuthStore";
export default defineNuxtPlugin(async (nuxtApp) => {
    const authStore = useAuthStore();
    authStore.checkAuthState();
});

My checkAuthState() is like this :
try {
   // Attempt to refresh the token if access is empty
   const axiosApi = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8000/api",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    },
    withCredentials: true,
    withXSRFToken: true,
    timeout: 10000,
  });
   await await axiosApi.post('/token/refresh/');
} catch (error) {
   console.error("Error refreshing token:", error);
   this.authenticated = false;
   return;
}

Here’s some additional information about my setup:
Frontend: Nuxt 3 with Axios.
Backend: Django (or specify your backend) running locally on port 8000.
I’m using http://localhost:8000 as the base URL for API requests.
Thanks in advance for your help!
Things I’ve already tried:
Verified that the backend is running and accessible via http://localhost:8000 in my browser.
Updated the Axios base URL to use http://localhost:8000.
Does anyone know what might be causing this issue or how I can fix it?

Does it work with a tool like hoppscotch (if you try to send the HTTP call from that tool)?
